# NFC Tag is not opening URL in Browser on Android

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I recorded an NDEF message on a Mifare Classic Tag that contains following URL:

```
http://192.168.195.104/micha/?id=1234
```

It links to my webserver from where i'd like to read Data from a Database on my Android Phone. When I type that address in the browser, the requested page opens just as it should. But when I try to open it using the NFC Tag a white screen appears which displays:

```
Arguments: http://192.168.195.104/micha/?id=1234
```

Storing other addresses (i tried google.com) works just fine. So I wonder if there is any known problem concerning the use of PHP or IP-addresses in NDEF records? Or any other idea why it isn't working?

Here the HEX Code of the message:

```
00 00 03 34 d1 01 1f 55 03 31 30 02 2e 31 36 38
2e 31 39 35 2e 31 30 34 2f 6d 69 63 68 61 2f 3f
69 64 3d 31 32 33 34 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This is really urgent, would be great if someone can help!

Comment: Not sure, but this might be related to encoding/decoding the url string? did you try to encode it before writing it to the tag & decode it after reading from the tag?

Comment: I did. First I encoded it myself by hand as specified by NFCForum and NXP Application Notes for Mifare. I wrote it on the tag with Arduino using NFC Shield. When it didnt work I used the Tag Writer App for Android to make sure I didnt do any mistake. Same data, same result. I decoded it by hand again, but it does not seem to have any miscoding.

Comment: @micha were you able to fix it, i am facing the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700286/write-data-uri-to-nfc-cheap-and-open-in-chrome-browser-android

Comment: @hanuman I was able to fix it using the accepted answer. Indeed I had multiple apps that made use of NFC and the intent was intercepted by another application. "adb logcat"  showed me which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work. In fact, I just tried it my self with a similar URL and it works on my device. So my guess is that another app on your phone is interfering and receiving the intent, instead of the browser. You can check by inspecting "adb logcat" to see to which package the intent is sent.